# Is it possible to have two Y axes and two X axes on the same chart for one variable?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2019, error-correction

How can I draw the correlation for calculating Y and R squared as scatter graph in *Excel 2019* for one variable, calculated with four models?

I want two models in two x-axis' and the other two in two y-axis'.

---

I want to make my temperature data for four models to be like this chart

[image: scientific chart]

[image: temperature datad for models]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words, particularly when talking about charts. Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: We could have two X axes and two Y axes in a scatter graph. Please refer to: [How to Create Secondary Horizontal/Vertical Axes in Microsoft EXCEL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84Al7vxBJCU). But I could not understand "**two models in two x-axis' and the other two in two y-axis'**", the data of series in scatter both need values on X-axis and Y-axis. You could have two models in primary axes and other two in secondary axes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure exactly what temperatures you're plotting against what other temperatures.

The ranges of the four axes are all overlapping, so it's kind of redundant plotting duplicate X and Y axes. But you have multiple series, so plot them all, then select one (or more) and assign it to the secondary axis. Use the plus icon next to the chart to make sure that you have all four axes, then format the axis scales so they all line up.